# How to get a validator function from a string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

**How can I convert the following string array into an array of types** (or functions?, or whatever these validators are...)**?**

```
let valStrings: string[] = ["Validators.required", "Validators.maxLength(10)"];
```

And convert it to:

```
let validators: ValidatorFn[] = [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ];
```

I have a web service returning the validation rules.  This is an attempt to centralize all our validation rules to keep server and client validation in sync, so the strings are coming from a `HttpClient` call with a JSON result. 
 Of course we still have the actual implementations separated, but at least the defined rules should be the same across both.

This array of validators would be passed into a `FormControl` to utilize reactive forms in Angular for client-side validation.

Is this a place where `eval()` should be used?

Thank you -Adam

Answer (score 5):

Defining validation on server by code of angular in a string is very bad idea. If you want dynamic validations create an API for that. Like:

```
validations: {
  name: {
    maxLength: 10,
    required: true
  }
}
```

Eval will not help you because that class is not bundled in the code. Also eval brings security risk and it should be disabled on your site by CSP.

Dont convert string to the code. You would need a parser for that. And what will you do when they change validations in Angular? Will you update all your forms?

Or imagine that you would connect with iOS app to your API. It would have to parse these string Angular validation rules.

Comment: Well I would update the "ClientValidationFunction" column in the database :).  I certainly hope they don't go making major changes with the validation.  I mean if I used the validation in code and they updated it, it would still be broken.  I'm not following you on the API, though.  Are you saying to simply parse the json body from my webservice (is that what the snippet in your answer represents) and apply the validation that way? I agree with eval, that's why I haven't explored that much.  Thanks

Comment: Ya basically define JSON API for defining your validations... then you check for what comes from API and you apply it in Angular. Imagine that you would hook up IOS app to your APP ... it would have to parse Angular code.

Comment: Yes that's a very good point.  Ideally the json would be client-platform agnostic and that dependency is no bueno...  I think I like this approach for the long term (that'll be written on my tombstone).  For now I took a similar approach to what Eliseo mentioned, but I'm going to hopefully have a chance to refactor that a bit after this sprint.

Comment: Ya that means you really need that parser like Eliseo made... I would avoid such solution even for short term.

Comment: @MartinNuc I am still not clear after defining API as you suggested how will we convert this keys to add corresponding validations to angular formcontrol?

Comment: @pratikch when building the form add validators based in the object keys.

Comment: so will have to keep somekind of mapping of string to actual validatorfn. I think I get that now.

Answer (score 3):

the only way I know is using a if

```
let valStrings: string[] = ["Validators.required", "Validators.maxLength(10)"];
let validators=valString.map(x=>{
    switch (x)
    {
        if (x=="Validators.required")
            return Validators.required;
        if (x.startsWith("Validators.maxLength")
        {
            let length=+(x.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]);
            return Validators.maxLength(length)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is very similar to what I ended up doing (I regex'ed the args off and use a switch statement, but other than that it's identical), but I would like to circle back when I get more time and approach this a little more like Martin suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of validation as under in an abstracted service and reusing where required.

```
export const schema = {
    "defaultValidations": {
        'title': [
            { name: 'required' },
            { name: 'minLength', args: [3] }
        ],
        'firstName': [
            { name: 'required' },
            { name: 'minLength', args: [3] },
            { name: 'maxLength', args: [50] }
        ]
    }
}

export interface Dictionary<T> {
    [Key: string]: T;
}

  validationMap: Dictionary<any> = {
    "required": (arg: any[]) => Validators.required,
    "minLength": (arg: number[]) => Validators.minLength(arg[0]),
    "maxLength": (arg: number[]) => Validators.maxLength(arg[0])
  };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  // validation functions
  mapValiations(key: string) :ValidatorFn[] {
    const validations = schema.defaultValidations[key]?.map(element => {
        return this.validationMap[element.name](element?.args);
     });

     return validations;
  }
```